# Radio app using flutter, audio stops after 3 mins when screen is off

Tags: flutter, timeout, internet-radio

We're developing an `IOS` & `Android` app for a Radio station, I'm actually the radio station owner and I'm trying to help out the developer.

We're currently only testing on Android and there is a problem when the screen turns off the radio app, plays for about 3 minutes, and then the audio stops. If I wake the phone up and turn the screen on, the audio starts again.

Is there a timeout setting or something in a flutter that does that? How can we avoid this, because as you understand there is no way to have a radio app to either require the screen to be always on or to stop after 3 minutes if the screen goes off.

Thank you

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service). It is a wrapper that works around a number of different audio plugins.